# How to change mat-icon when sidenav is closed by click anywhere in the body

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a sidenav which gets toggled when clicked on a mat-icon . I have added mat-icon change when the mat-icon is used to toggle the sidenav .

But i am unable to change the icon when the sidenav is closed by clicking anywhere else in the body of the page . I want to change back the mat-icon back to the original icon when closed .

Currently the code that i have for changing mat-icon on click of icon is -

```
 <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="2%" (click)="snav.toggle();changeIcon();">
  <mat-icon class="IconColor" *ngIf="!menuIconToggle">menu</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon class="IconColor" *ngIf="menuIconToggle">arrow_back</mat-icon>
</div>
```

On the ts side -

```
 changeIcon() {
this.menuIconToggle = !this.menuIconToggle;
```

}

Can anyone help in changing the icon when sidenav is closed by clicking anywhere else on the screen . Thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes , mat-sidenav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using material sidenav component you can use [opened](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatDrawer) input property to check whether the sidenav open or close

**component.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="2%" (click)="snav.toggle();changeIcon();">
  <mat-icon class="IconColor" *ngIf="!snav.opened">menu</mat-icon>
  <mat-icon class="IconColor" *ngIf="snav.opened">arrow_back</mat-icon>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Component.html**

```
    <mat-icon (click)="toggleMenu()" >{{ isMenuOpen ? 'close' : 'menu' }} 
    </mat-icon>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-header',
templateUrl: './header.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    isMenuOpen=false;
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.isMenuOpen = !this.isMenuOpen;
    }
}
```